# How to get first change of column for a row in Oracle table through SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, data-warehouse

Dimension tables type 2 record changes for a row over time (SCD). I'd like to find the first value change for a column based on another column say date (should be common pattern).

For e.g., employee table with (emp_id, insert_date, status, address) where status indicates working, not_working, vacation etc (a few fixed values). This strange company keeps tabs on employees every day, say. Now I want to know when employee started last vacation in the last one year. The following will not work

```
select distinct empid, max(insert_date) where status = 'vacation'
where insert_date > today - 1 year --- know not correct syntax but to simplify
group by empid
```

as it'll pick last record with status vacation but there could be many records with vacation as records could have changed for other reasons like address changes etc for e.g.,:

```
emp_id insert_dt status     address
1      9/1/2019   working   123
1      9/2/2019   working   1234
1      9/3/2019   vacation  1234
1      9/4/2019   vacation  12345   --- address change
1      9/5/2019   working   12345
```

So I'd like to the first occurrence of the switch from working to vacation which is 9/3 (not 9/4) and min would not work either.

We can't change the table schema nor do PL/SQL nor use SQL embedded in some programming language etc., just plain SQL. If you know any (analytic) function in Oracle that can run a lambda or mimic it with  encoding columns etc., it would be ideal.

Thanks
S

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by emp_id order by insert_dt) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where status = 'vacation' and
      (prev_status <> status or prev_status is null);
```

EDIT:

If you want the most recent time for an employee, you can use aggregation:

```
select emp_id, max(insert_dt)
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by emp_id order by insert_dt) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where status = 'vacation' and
      (prev_status <> status or prev_status is null)
group by emp_id;
```

You can add filtering as well for a particular period of time.

Comment: but this would give me all the records that had the switch. If I want to know the last time/date an employee started vacation in the past one year, I need to wrap this in another select use last_value() by partitioning on emp_id and order by insert_dt desc, isn't it? If so is there a more efficient way (i can't see one without knowing the cardinalities)?

Answer (score 0):

> So I'd like to the first occurrence of the switch from working to vacation

I would first use `lag()` to get the previous status for each `emp_id`, ordered by `insert_dt`. Then, identify records where status switched from working to vacation, and rank them by `insert_dt` for each employee. Finally, filter on the first record per employee:

```
select e.*
from (
    select 
        e.*,
        row_number() over(partition by emp_id order by insert_dt) rn
    from (
        select
            e.*,
            lag(status) over(partition by emp_id order by insert_dt) lag_status
        from employee e
        where insert_date > add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12)
    ) e
    where lag_status = 'working' and status = 'vacation'
) e
where rn = 1
```

Comment: GMB, aren't you doing the same as I said in my comment to Gordon? To get the last time don't I have to sort the row_number by insert_dt, descending?

Comment: @Noname: yes this query gives you one record per employee, with the first time they switched from working status to vacation. If you want the last time instead, then you can indeed change `row_number()` to `order by insert_dt desc`.